# git push するとき、dev と origin/dev は何が違うのでしょうか？

Tags: git

下記のgit pushコマンドについて質問です。

1のコマンドではリモートリポジトリのdevブランチに、現在のHEADをプッシュすると考えているのですが、2の場合は何が違うのでしょうか？

1. `git push origin dev`
2. `git push origin origin/dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、[Git で「追跡ブランチ」って言うのやめましょう - Qiita](https://qiita.com/uasi/items/69368c17c79e99aaddbf) の説明と図がわかりやすいかなと思いますのでそちらの説明を読んでみてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

リンク先の説明でわかる通り、ひとくちに `master` と言っても、 ローカルに `master` と　`origin/master`の2つと、リモートに `master` の1つが一般的には関わってきます。

さて、 `git push origin dev` コマンドは、　ローカルの `dev` ブランチをリモートの `dev` ブランチに同期させるコマンドです。
("現在のHEADをプッシュする" わけではありません)

同様に、 `git push origin origin/dev` は、ローカルの `origin/dev` ブランチをリモートの `origin/dev` ブランチに同期させるコマンドということになります。

`origin/dev` ブランチは冒頭リンク先の説明にある通りリモートを追跡しているブランチなので、それをリモートにpushするという行為は普通に考えて意味が無いです。
従って **2. のようなコマンドを実行する機会は無いでしょう**。

---

(完全ではないですが、私がわかるところまで説明してみます)

実際に何が起こっているのかは、次のような手順で確認することができると思います。

まず、ローカルにリモート(origin)リポジトリとローカルリポジトリを作成します。

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
mkdir origin-repo
cd origin-repo
git init --bare
cd ..
git clone origin-repo local-repo
cd local-repo
```

この時点のリモートリポジトリの refs を見てみます。

```
tree ../origin-repo/refs/
```

結果:

```
../origin-repo/refs
├── heads
└── tags
```

続いて、ローカルでcommit, pushをおこなった後、同様にリモートリポジトリの refs を確認してみます。

```
git commit --allow-empty -m init
git push origin HEAD
tree ../origin-repo/refs/
```

結果:

```
../origin-repo/refs/
├── heads
│   └── main
└── tags
```

`refs/heads/main` が作成されているのがわかります。
続いて、 `origin/main` を push してみます。

```
git push origin origin/main
tree ../origin-repo/refs/
```

結果:

```
../origin-repo/refs/
├── heads
│   └── main
├── remotes
│   └── origin
│       └── main
└── tags
```

`refs/remotes/origin/main` が作成されました。

ところで、このブランチは `git branch -r` で表示されません。
checkout するには被らないような名前のローカルブランチにpullすれば良さそうです。

```
git pull origin origin/main:origin-main
git checkout origin-main
```

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。
いただいた資料を拝見し、リモート追跡ブランチや上流ブランチという概念について把握できていないことに気がつけました。。
掲載していただいたデモも行いながら理解を深めていきます。

Answer (score 3):

"origin/dev" ブランチは、"origin" というリモートの "dev" というブランチに対する「リモート追跡ブランチ」です。これに対して "dev" ブランチはローカルのブランチです。

詳しくは Pro Git の解説が分かりやすいです: [Git のブランチ機能 - リモートブランチ](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD-%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81)